# specifying image src as dynamic state variable in React Native

Tags: image, react-native, url, dynamic, native

I want to load an image in react native. I have gone through many posts but almost every post talks about specifying static / local url’s of image as a source. However , I want to specify it as

src= {this.state.url}

Where this.state.url is assigned a dynamic url (from google images )within the code.

Is it possible ?

Comment: You can definitely use external images in React Native with e.g. `<Image source={{ uri: 'https://example.com/image.png' }} />`, but requiring images can not be dynamic since React Native must know what images to bundle in the final build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Tholle answer

> Image source={{ uri: 'https://example.com/image.png' }}

But in your render() make it changes as so :

```
render(){

 var image = ( <Image source={{this.state.url}} /> );

 return(

  <View>

   {image}

  </View>

 )

}
```

So whenever your component state will change, render will be called with the updated url I think

Comment: It Works!! But instead of this.state.url, i want it to be fetched from a dictionary having random elements like this.state.dict[2].url . Is it possible ?

Comment: Sure it is :) you just need to have a valid URL at this moment, that's all